# How can I change the name of an iOS app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I began an iPhone project the other day with a silly development code name, and now I want to change the name of the project since it's nearly finished. How can I do this?

Comment: I've had to do this a few times. I use a tool called Rename Xcode Project 2.1.

Comment: There are times when the simple way still doesn't work (or there are echoes of old naming, etc.). I posted an article showing how to fix this by going into the xml of the project files manually here: [change the name of an iPhone app](http://pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=29)

Comment: Here's a free utility that does this and works well in my experience: [change the name of an iPhone app](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/17683)

Comment: **@all:** Not fully answered. The title of the application window and the pulldown menu of the application stays with the old name. **@Frank Schmitt:** The "Rename xCode Project" project fails when the plist file was renamed. It awaits the name Info.plist

Comment: Change the name of the file, the very first in the list.

Comment: For rookies, the [Xcode 5 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/1296746) is correct and way easier.

Comment: Note: You can also change it in InfoPlist.strings so that it's localized for different languages.. Somehow no one posted an answer for that :(

Comment: Can we change the name without using Xcode ? From any command on terminal ?

Answer (score 1143, accepted):

1. Go to *Targets* in Xcode.
2. *Build Settings* on your project's target (your current development name).
3. Search for *Product Name* under *Packaging*. Change its value to what you want your new project name to be.

[image: ProductName]

Comment: I had to quit XCode and delete my build directory before it would take for me.

Comment: Also, remember to change this in each of the configurations! (Debug, Release, Ad Hoc, App Store, etc)

Comment: For anyone else that is a complete beginner, "Targets" is inside of the "Groups & Files" pane on the left, it has a red and white target sign next to it ;)

Comment: Example of above comment:
2010-07-03 10:56:35.129 OldAppName [45672.207] Test Message
-
Even though I have changed the Product_name, ".app" name Bundle name, etc...
-
Where does "Console" get this name, so I can truly change the app's name 100%?

Comment: Don't know why am I an exception but It didn't worked for me :(

Comment: In Xcode 4 you can simply double click the target name and change it directly in the target list.

Comment: After doing the mentioned steps I get a Code Sign error: The identity 'bla' doesn't match any identity in any profile.

Comment: This needs updating, the given answer and associated comments are very confusing and don't seem to match what I see in Xcode 5.x

Comment: In latest version of xcode I get error saying "unable to change app permission something after changing the name". All I did was uninstall the app and ran the ">" button again. It worked like magic

Comment: If your app uses `iCloud` or `Push Notifications` or some other service, and you change `Product Name` you will also need to recreate Provisioning Profile for your app. But still, that is far better than renaming project folder in Finder and then re-include all files into Xcode :)

Comment: @all there is a really good and updated answer for Xcode5 that worked like a charm, and i think it's the correct one check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/3027848

Comment: This is not a good answer, if you change the name in following this steps your unit test are not going to work!

Comment: After selecting Target. Find "Product Name" in "Packaging" under build settings.

Comment: @hallski (1000 yrs later... ) It still works in Xcode6!

Comment: Go to Targets / Build Settings / and look for Packaging to change Product Name. My app uses CloudKit and works fine (XCode 8, Swift 3)

Comment: In Xcode >= 8 just select target > General tab and write your app new name in "Display Name" Column. Done!!

Comment: Does not work. Why is this crap answer being protected?

Comment: If you have localization, change the 'CFBundleDisplayName' key in InfoPlist.strings file.

Comment: XCode no longer has "Targets" menu items

Comment: The info is useful but I gave you a thumbs up because seen the number 999 was driving me crazy :-)

Comment: It is worked in 2021, Xcode 12. I alway cannot name a good one the time I create my project!

Comment: Can we change the name without using Xcode ? From any command on terminal

Comment: It makes me feel nostalgic...

Comment: Basic guidelines https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/

Answer (score 393):

In new versions of Xcode (**Xcode 5 too**), to change the name of the project, follow these simple (detailed as possible) steps:

**Note:** In this example I'll change a hypothetical "Sample" name to a "Test" one.

1. Click twice **slowly** on the project root in the project navigator and then it becomes editable.

   [image]
2. Rename the project.

   [image]
3. After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the assistant will suggest you to automatically change all project-name-related entries and will allow you to de-select some of them, if you want.

   [image]
4. Press 'RENAME' and Xcode will do the rest. In the meanwhile Xcode may ask you about the option of making a snapshot of the project (it is very recommendable to do so).
5. In addition to renaming the project, you may want to rename the scheme so that it matches your new project name.

   [image]
6. Repeat similar steps like 1 and 2, and press OK.

   [image]

   [image]
7. That's it.

**Another scenario...**

The previous explanation was related to changing the project name, but chances are that you only need to change the display name that appears below the app icon in the home screen. These are the steps:

1. In the "Supporting Files" group locate the *info.plist* (or related) file
2. Locate the "Bundle display name" key and change the value to the new name.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Delete the "old" app from the simulator or any other testing device.
4. Clean and rebuild your app again.
5. That's it. You will now see the new app name in your home screen.

Comment: The scheme change didn't go smoothly for me: could only select My Mac after that. Thankfully the problem is easy to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device

Comment: Had the same problem as @marcelsalathe, his fix solved the issue. Ideally this should be added to Javier Cadiz's answer.

Comment: There is a bug with Xcode where the rename function doesn't rename shared internal framework properly. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749687/shared-internal-framework-not-found-after-renaming-project/34933948#34933948

Comment: The "Another scenario" worked great! Two notes: 1. I had to add the "Bundle Display Name" in Info.plist as it was not there by default (Xcode 7). 2. If it doesn't appear to work, make sure you're changing the bundle display name in the Info.plist file in the "Supporting Files" folder like Javier said. I wasn't paying close enough attention and changed it in the ProjectName-Info.plist file that is right below the "Supporting Files" folder and wondered why nothing happened.

Comment: **Important note**: This won't rename some files and folders! You can use some `sed` magic to fix this afterward, though.

Comment: This *should* be a good route but will lead most devs to a lost day or two. It is such a nightmare, especially if you have a bunch of pods active. I'd highly suggest Sahil Kapoor's advice above, and REALLY REALLY ponder a project's name prior to starting.

Comment: Pure GOLD. Thanks for this. As a flutter dev, and not an Apple Xcode experienced dev, I find xcode a nightmare. Why they dont give it a search bar is beyond me ;-)

Comment: This approach also updates the name of the app in the launch screen, which many of the other answers here fail to do. Life saver, thank you!

Answer (score 222):

You change the bundle display name in the *info.plist* file. It's as simple as that.

Changing the 'bundle display name' (as opposed to 'bundle name') is the only way to include characters like '+' in your applications name. Including special characters in the project name will cause an error when uploading to [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS))!

Comment: this is better than changing the target name as it avoids conflict and mess-ups in game engines

Comment: i had to change the product name in info plist and also rename the target name. Then I also had to clean build directory (press and hold options key while traversing to xcode Product menu and there will be an option to clean build directory).

Comment: This changes the app name displayed under the icon without the hassle of changing the app id and provisioning profiles. Thanks. Accepted answer no longer applies (as I understand it).

Comment: This is by far the superior solution! *JUST* changes the name under the icon, and not bundle identifiers which mess up provisioning profiles

Comment: If 'Bundle display name' is not shown, then simply add it.

Comment: Can we change the name without using Xcode ? From any command on terminal ?

Answer (score 148):

In Xcode 4, search for "Product Name" under "Build Settings" tab of the target.

Comment: This is a bad answer, if you do that your test project won't run

Comment: ...and 118 other people apparently!

Comment: This would works great only with one issue, on your user's devices it will create a separate application with the new name instead of renaming the currently installed one they already have.

Changing the 'bundle display name' in the project plist is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 53):

1. Select Target

   [image: Target selected in Xcode sidebar.]
2. Select Info

   [image: Info tab selected.]
3. Insert Bundle Display Name and set App Title

   [image: Dropdown showing Application Category highlighted.]

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't mess up with other file names and identifiers, and mostly - doesn't change the Bundle Identifier - which is essential if you already have an app id...

Answer (score 48):

If you want to change the display name only then you can directly change it in the property file (plist) of the app.

You can add a new row with the following key: **Bundle display name**

Here is an example for this:

[image]

When you use this the app name, which you have given with this key, it will be displayed.

So you can do this simply.

Comment: Note = The start of "bundle" have to be capatilized... Correct one is : "Bundle display name"

Answer (score 40):

This is how I changed it in Xcode 4:

1. Click on your target file (the first main file of the application).
2. Go to *Build Settings*.
3. Scroll down you will find a bar called "Packaging".
4. Under *Packaging* you will see *Product Name*, and you can change the project name.

Comment: This works, but it also changes the deployed app name (any existing installs won't get "upgraded", it will be a second app). Changing the "bundle display name" as per @CodeHunter's answer is nicer

Answer (score 38):

In Xcode 3.2, just select the Project entry in the Groups & Files panel, and select the menu item *Project* → *Rename…* It worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

Xcode 7/8? It's in the [plist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) that your target uses:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

**For Xcode 10.2:**

Although this question has many answers but I wanted to explain the whole concept in detail so that everyone can apply this knowledge to further or previous versions of Xcode too.

Every Xcode project consists of one or more targets. According to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html), `A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions for building the product from a set of files in a project or workspace.` So every target is a product (app) on its own.

Steps to change the name:

**Step 1:** Go to the ***Targets*** and open the ***Info*** tab of the target whose name you want to change.

**Step 2:** View the **Bundle name** key under the *Custom iOS Target Properties* that is set to the default property of `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`.

[image]

**Step 3:** You can either change the **Bundle name** directly (not recommended) or if you open the ***Build Settings*** tab then on searching for **Product Name** under *Setting* you will see that **Product Name** is set to `$(TARGET_NAME)`.

[image]

**Step 3A:** You can change the **Product Name** or you can also change the **Target Name** by double clicking on the target.

[image]

So changing the **Product Name** *(App Name)* or **Target Name** both will result into similar results. But if you only want to change the **App Nam**e and want to keep using the same **Target Name** then only change the **Product Name**.

Answer (score 22):

For Xcode 11, if you want to change the App Display Name then simply go to plist and simply replace the value of `CFBundleDisplayName`:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Your App Name</string>
```

Comment: What about when we have multiple schemes? Thanks!

Comment: What is "plist"? A file?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes its a file and it has your applications configurations in it

Comment: This will NOT update your splash screen (aka launch screen) with the new app name. In order to update your splash screen, you must make the changes to the app name directly in Xcode.

Answer (score 21):

From Xcode 4.2 and onwards, you can use one more option.
Just click once on the .proj file name at the top in left navigation pane and it will be available for renaming. Rename it and the whole project will get renamed and not only the target.

Answer (score 20):

The best way I like in Xcode 5 is to change product name in building settings. Search "product name" in "building settings", and change it.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

If you need to change the name of the application as it appears on the iPhone's home screen, you need to do it in the *Target* configuration, not the project configuration.

1. Expand the *Targets* group in Xcode, and then single-click the item under that. It should share the name of your project, which is also the default name of the application that gets generated.
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the *Info* window, and then navigate to the Build tag.
3. Set the *Configuration* drop-down to read *All Configurations*.
4. Look for a setting called *Product Name* under the *Packaging* heading.
5. Change that value to the name you want for your compiled applications and, in the immortal words of [Bugs Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugs_Bunny): Voilà! Do a clean and a build. Your application will take on the new name.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the name, that will be displayed on your screen, right under your icon, in Xcode 4, go to *Targets* → *Info* → *Bundle Display Name* and change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 16):

In Xcode 4, click on project name to start renaming.

Comment: I saw the setting as "Product Name" not "Project Name" - in any case, the change worked.

Comment: The old iPhone OS 2.x SDK had it as "Program Name". It was changed with 3.0 SDK to "Product name".

Comment: But renaming the project at the `Product Name` under `Build settings-> Packaging` is primordial step otherwise it will be some issues when submitting the final release.

Answer (score 14):

It's very easy to change in Xcode 8. enter the app name in the "Display Name" field in *Project Target* → *General Identity* section.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Also: your target name may be the same as your app name. Note that changing the target name does not change the app name. Only the change in the target properties described below will change the app name.

Comment: Can we change the name without using Xcode ? From any command on terminal

Answer (score 12):

You can modify the *Product Name* without changing your *Project Name* (especially the directory).

*Build Settings* → search the keyword "**product name**" → *Update values*

Answer (score 11):

A note on the bundle display name: This is the right way to change the name in your app menu, but you'll likely have to reset content and settings in your iOS simulator before you see the change actually take effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? E.g., instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

For the sake of gathering all relevant information in one place, here is the [official answer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html) to this question - and it is the only one that worked for me on Xcode 5.1.1

Just use the Identity and Type pane in Xcode.

[image: Use Identity and Type pane in Xcode]

Answer (score 8):

1. Select the top-most line to the left (with your project name, number of targets, etc.).
2. Select the target you wish to rename.
3. Click on the name of the target again.
4. Type the new name.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

For changing the application name only (that will display along with the app icon) in Xcode 4 or later:

Click on your project file icon from Groups & Files panel, choose *Target* → *Build Settings* → *Packaging* → *Product Name*. Click on the row. A pop-up will come. Type your new app name here.

For changing the project name only (that will display along with project icon) in Xcode 4 or later:

Click on your project file icon from the *Groups & Files* panel, choose *Project* (above targets) from the right pane. Just see at the far right pane (it will be visible only if you have enabled "Hide or show utilities"). Look for the project name. Edit it to a new name you want to give your project.

Delete your app from simulator/device, clean and run. Changes should reflect.

That's it.

Answer (score 8):

I saw many ways to change your app name on the home screen, and I don't think the necessity of edit your `.plist` file or changing *Build Settings* of target is justified.

By default in Xcode 7.2 you even don't have 'bundle display name' in your `plist` file.

And by default, your 'Product name' in 'Build settings' tab of your target is equal to `$(TARGET_NAME)`. IMHO, it's convenient and didn't mean to change.

So you can simply change your Target name like **hallski** said in his comment for accepted answer. I made picture for it:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a bit of confusion:

- Do you want to change the **project name** or
- do you want to change the **App name** on the iOS dashboard?

Usually it is enough to change the latter, adding/modifying the BUNDLE DISPLAY NAME key in plist.

It is better to leave the project name untouched, but it may be changed.

Note that Bundle display Name *can* contain spaces and special characters, but project *not*. Doing so some cmd line tools will fail due to filename path rules.

And even more Bundle Display names can be localized.

So unless you are in early stage and need to change the *internal* project name, go on using the Bundle Display Name key.

Answer (score 8):

*Project Navigator* → *General* → *Display Name*

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are

- `Product name` (`$(PRODUCT_NAME)`): defaults to `Target name`. This is useful for `scheme` to select the right target
- `Bundle display name` (`CFBundleDisplayName`): defaults to `Product name`. This is what is displayed to your iOS user

Answer (score 7):

Follow these four steps maintaining the serial number. And in step 4, give your desired name...

step 1: Click on your project

step 2: Click on the target

step 3: Click on the General tab

step 4: Under identity click on Display name and change it.

You can see details on the image.

Shortcut: -> Just look at the image

[image]

Comment: What serial number?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way: select the TARGET name, double click on it, and rename.

You'll see your app's new name underneath the icon on your device or simulator.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Javier's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/3962892) to rename my app works perfectly. There is just one small bit missing in the end that I wanted to add.

I still ended up getting a Mach-O Linker Error after a clean and rebuild. To resolve this; select yourProject (in the Project Navigator). Under Targets, select yourProjectTests (the test target) → under the *General* tab, update the Host Application's value to the newly renamed project.

Answer (score 6):

In *Target* → *Build Setting* → *Product name* field, you can edit that field here.

Answer (score 6):

Select project navigator → *select Target* → *Identity* → *Display Name* → *Name*.

Answer (score 5):

I am using this script after I rename my iOS project. It helps to change the directories name and make the names in sync.

http://github.com/ytbryan/rename

NOTE: you will need to manually change the scheme's name.

Answer (score 4):

The link below works for Xcode 6, especially if you are getting an error after trying to rename your project. Basically, just try building a new scheme of your app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572164/4114835

Answer (score 2):

Use *Target* → *Build Setting* → *Product name*.

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Comment: By this, I tried to make it short and clear. Usually, I look for these kind of answers.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/239006/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 13, if you want to change the App Display Name then simply go to plist and simply replace the value of CFBundleDisplayName: using that you can display the name of application.
In the .plist file you need added this.

CFBundleDisplayName
Your App Name

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the CFBundleDisplayName in the InfoPlist.strings file.

Comment: The question is asking how to rename a project. Your solution only changes the name that appears below the app icon on a user's device.