# Weird iPhone Simulator Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I have a question.  WHen I changed the executable name in my info.plist file in Xcode, the simulator would no longer load the application.  When I changed it back to '${EXECUTABLE_NAME}', the simulator worked fine. Any reason as to why this would affect the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the answer to this question might help:

[ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app)