# How to change iPhone App name 100%!

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Can't seem change the name of my iPhone app 100%.

I followed multiple threads and performed the outlined methods below, but the old name keeps popping back up in Console.  I'm concerned that on some deeper level the app's name has not really been changed 100%.

My concern is with the fact that I've made a "Lite" version by starting with a copy of the "Full" version. So I don't want the device to get confused if my customers upgrade and download the full version and the device see two apps with the same "CORE or ROOT" name.

Console continues to output:
 
    `2010-07-03 10:56:35.129 *OldAppName* [45672.207] Test Message`

I have changed the Product_name, ".app" name, Bundle name, etc... - Where does "Console" get this name, so I can truly change the app's name 100%?  I don't want an conflicts with the full version down the road as the apps grown independently in complexity. (i.e. Push Notifications, iAds, and other "APP" specific items)

I have performed the following, but still not getting 100% name change:

---

I.  I have used Xcode, Project, Rename.

II.  I have used the suggested answer on stackoverflow thread,    [Changing iPhone App's Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app), to

1. Go to Targets in Xcode,
2. "Get Info" on your project's target (your current silly development name),
3. Search for "Product Name" under "Packaging". Change the value of that what you want the new program name is going to be.

My "Product_Name" field was blank for all builds, I changed it to the new name, but I continue to get the console output referencing the **OldAppName**.

III.  I'm not trying to change the "Bundle Name", those are the same, as this is a Lite Version.  And changing this does not change the Console reference name anyway, I tried.

IV.  I have deleted the entire "Build" folder several times to assure no legacy issues, but the name still does not change.

---

I'm currently working on a large copy/paste migration over to a new project to try and fix this completely with a new project, because I would like to get app uploaded to the AppStore asap, but there must be a better way of achieving this.

Where does the "Console" get this name?  Does this mean that if my customers' download the full version that on some deeper level the device will get confused-(i.e. NSUserDefaults with the same names, running issue, sandbox issues, etc...)?

The names are not stored in the info.plist, they appear to just be referenced from the target, but when I search through the target, I don't even find the OldAppName, is their an additional storage file for this core information?

I would like to stay in Xcode if possible.  I have seen suggestions about using other programs or trying to change the XML directly through text editor, but I don't want to accidentally leave a "Third-Party" application marker or trial that might get rejected by Apple Reviewer's as they seem to be coming down hard on this issue.

Any detailed suggestions??

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app/35595894#35595894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only Solution that Worked, and it was the one that feared the most and was trying to avoid.**

I had to start a new project and painstakingly move all 96 class files (about 27mb of text) over one by one, because dragging the classes over kept giving me an error. I tried dragging over the classes as one large group, but that would not work.  A little "re-factoring", rebuilding the .plist info, and setting up the new targets, and it I got it working again.  I think that there was some sort of legacy issues that Xcode was getting caught up on.

It is working now under a new project, but there must be a better way.

Comment: This way is the last hope of an iOS Developer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem about a year ago.

I've got really nice & easy solution for your needs. You need to click on the "superview" of blue icon (Project/Targets) and then hit enter to change the name of the project. You can also double click on that field, but you need to do it with quite a long delay between clicks.

This method will change magically name of the project in all important places.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f1RD.png

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening *all* files in your project in a text editor and searching for the old name?

Have you tried creating a new empty project and merely adding your content and code files to this empty project?

Comment: No I have not, that is a good idea that I will look into, which files or classes would be more applicable to having this type of stored data?  I have several hundred files?I have been working on trying to move all the files over, however Xcode is giving me an "Can not copy class files message."  It appears that all the files come over, but I have not been able to get a clean build.  I get this error....(Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1).

Comment: I started a new project and painstakingly moved all the files over one by one, because dragging the classes over kept giving me an error.  I think that there was some sort of legacy issues that Xcode was getting caught up on.  Is working now, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I have done these in the past and found they work fine:

http://drjunker.org/2008/04/10/xcode-rename-project-and-application-change-copyright-and-version-number/

http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C1216817469/E1454445171/index.html

I also Clean All Targets/Builds and rename the Executable after.

Comment: I gave the first one a try and still getting same result.  I will try the second one and see what I can get.  Thanks, I'll let you know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when there was a localized strings (infoPlist.strings) file in project with "CFBundleDisplayName"="MyOldAppName" in it. Removing this file and renaming target to my NewAppName worked for me.