# Bundle Identifier Read Only

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an application that has a bundle identifier of my application.

> com.sc.Quitchen_ap

I want to change it but the application won't let me do it as the part is read-only. I really need to change the name to quitchen instead of quitchen_ap. Please check the image below.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Change the target name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362299/renaming-targets-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to trojanfoe. The answer is in the other link. Let me complete this question answer.

**1. Chose the Build Target your application.**

[image]

**2. Then click on the Build Settings.**

[image]

**3. Then Look for the Packaging section and change the name of the product. **"Product Name"****

[image]

**4. You will see the name changed in the SUMMARY tab of the application.**

[image]

THANKS @trojanfoe