# Naming an iOS app for submission

Tags: ios, xcode, product, submission

iTunes Connect accepts names for the app to include symbols like "+". But when I am trying to submit the app with an Xcode project name that includes "+" I receive the error that the name of the project or the name of the application (or product, do not remember which) cannot include symbols like "+". So I ended up removing the "+" symbol from the name of the product. Therefore the name on the App Store includes "+" but when installed on the device the name does not include the symbol "+". How can I resolve this issue in the next submission? What name will be the name of the app on the device? How can it include "+" and pass the test for submission?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you ONLY want to change the app "Display Name", this is the name that appears on the users iPhone when they download the app.

1.) Go to your info.plist and add a new line, set the Key to "Bundle Display Name."

2.) Enter whatever name you would like up to 12 Characters. This can include ANY character you want. i.e. +_)(*&^%$#@!

If you ever having issues with the app name not matching with the name setup in iTunes Connect then double click slowly on the Xcode Project name on the top left. Change this name and a window will pop up asking you to rename the whole project, select yes and the name of your project will be change. This is where you need to make sure the names match in both Xcode and iTunes Connect.

Comment: I am planning an update within a week or so. What you explained sounds very savvy. I will try it out and let you know if it actually works for me. Thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: Thanks a lot dana! Bundle display name was indeed the answer. Now I have the name of the app on the App Store and on the device with ++.

Comment: I can't get this to work in 2015. Anyone have success with this or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Project info -> Targets (click on app icon entry) -> Build Settings -> Product Name

from: [Change name of iPhone app in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043066/change-name-of-iphone-app-in-xcode-4/8109014#8109014)

A quick app store search and purchase shows that iTunes Connect allows for unicode symbols (those include !@#$%^&*-+= also).  But for an app bundle name, it is invalid.  Punctutuation symbols are OK (As in the app Where's My Water's title on the device is just 'Water?').

Comment: Last time I tried the Product Name that included "+" did not pass the test for the sole reason of the name including a symbol. Are you saying that Product Name can include symbols and should pass the test?

Comment: In iTunes connect, app bundle names are treated like file names, so spaces are converted to %20's and so forth.  The device however, I don't know.  I don't think it treats those symbols as invalid.  Unicode symbols might also be a  good bet.  Does the app name have to include a plus?  What about going into ITC and making the app store name have a plus, but in Xcode, spell out the word "plus"

Comment: Thanks! Well, I want to be as consistent as possible as far as the name on the App Store and on the device. It's actually ++ so PlusPlus would be too much :-)

Comment: On the device, consistency isn't an issue so much as getting an app name short enough to not have a ... in it.  PlusPlus would be a great app name on the device.