# Invalid Signature (Invalid Binary) on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I know is a duplicate question, but on all other questions i cant find a solution, so i retry to post question with more details.

I archive my app on `xcode5` for `iOS7` with `Release Scheme` and correct `Provisioning Distribution`

that's the screen:

This is on `Project`

[image]

And This is on `Target`

[image]
[image]

I try to do many different asset, i'am sure to my `Building Archive` is on `Release` but the answer of `iTunesConnect` is every time the same:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "MyApp". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a
>   distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development
>   certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are
>   correct at the target level (which override any values at the project
>   level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built
>   using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are
>   certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in
>   Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your
>   release target.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

And `Invalid Binary`

I become to crazy to understand how to sole this issue, any body have idea to do this?

Thanks.

****Test Response****

[image]

**Athority Screen**
 is correct

[image]

Comment: Have you tried everything they have said, if you have it would sort the issue out. I'm going to assume you have missed something or misunderstood what they are saying. Also them images are pretty pointless as you have made it so we can't actually see the type of provisioning profile being used.

Comment: I add new screen, i says i try to many different sets not all ;)

Comment: Don't edit the question to show the solution, add the solution as an answer, currently I do not know hate you are asking

Comment: Agreed please don't edit the question but instead answer your own question.

Comment: Have A look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711335/ios-missing-or-invalid-signature-the-bundle-is-not-signed-using-an-apple-submis/34020050#34020050).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode, at the target level do the following:

1. First choose the provisioning profile for the Release configuration. (For `Any SDK`)
   The provisioning profile **must** match the app's `Bundle ID` (As you can see in the General tab).
2. In the code signing identity, tap on the sub-menu for `Any iOS SDK` and make sure you choose `Automatic`. If you can't see below.
3. **Clean All** and **Archive**.

Choosing CodeSign identity:

In step 2, if you can't choose `Automatic`, then it means you might not have a match between the AppID and the app's Bundle ID.
The AppID is pointed by the provisioning profile you chose.

If this is the case, then login in the developer portal and make sure that the provisioning profile you used points to the correct AppID.

To verify the the .ipa or .app before you submit try these commands.
Then look at the printout, and see if all looks right. Also verify the expiration date.

```
$cd <where the app is>
$unzip *.ipa
$cd Payload
$codesign -d --entitlement - *.app
$codesign --verify -dvvv *.app
$security cms -D -i *.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

Comment: I do everything but continue to the same error (I'am sure the profile poit to correct appId) cms+k cleaning all remove all archive but still continue to says Invalid Binary T_T

Comment: Thanks for your update, add a result screen and i think is correct, but have same response... Invalid Binary T_T

Comment: OK, thats the embedded.mobileprovisioning output. Now from the output of the codesign commands, verify that the identifier match and look for "Authority=" with the name of the mobile provisioning file - is that the one you used?

Comment: Yeah... adding a screen

Comment: Do you use Xcode for submission? If so it probably asks you to choose certificate before submission. I suggest that you will save the archive as .ipa file, then do the verification above. And for submission, use the "Application Loader" app instead of Xcode.

Comment: No i try to upload from xcode and Application loader, but result the same error ...  psychologist I'Am coming!!! T_T

Comment: :)  So I assume that if you use Application Loader the verification works. Do you have multiple certificate and mobile provisioning installed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47884/discussion-between-tsafrir-and-jhon)

Answer (score 2):

In Apple developer support, I've seen two additional common causes of the `Invalid Signature` binary rejection reason,

1. executable files containing special characters (i.e. non-numeric, and non-alpha). To resolve this issue, change the Xcode target’s Product Name build setting from “${TARGET_NAME} to a string containing only alpha/numeric characters. Let me know if this was the cause of the issue (and the problematic characters) because I file bug reports to fix each instance I find here.
2. Apple Double Files ("double files") that result from copying the Xcode project uncompressed to/from a non HFS+ formatted hard drive. To check if this caused your rejection:

A. Run the app diagnostic here: [How do I check if my application's signature has been corrupted?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG38)

B. Then check the command line output with: [List of Signature Verification Failure Root Causes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG39). Double files are diagnosed with a message like:

```
resource missing: my.app/._.*
```

C. From the docs:

> The file prefixed with "._" is considered an AppleDouble file and it
>   can result from copying the uncompressed Xcode project folder onto a
>   non-HFS+ formatted disk. The AppleDouble files must be removed using
>   the 'dot_clean' command. The Xcode project folder is the argument to
>   dot_clean as illustrated below. Note: You can drag your Xcode project
>   folder from Finder into the Terminal window to automatically fill its
>   path into the command.

```
        dot_clean /path/to/My_Xcode_Project
```

(If Terminal can't find the dot_clean utility, download the optional Command Line Tools through Xcode > Preferences > Downloads)

D. After running `dot_clean` on your Xcode project, create a new app archive (via Xcode > Product > Archive), reattempt submission.

To prevent double files be sure to compress the Xcode project folder to .zip using Finder before transferring it to/from a non HFS+ formatted hard drive.

Comment: Thanks! For (1), might be worth mentioning that you can have special characters in the app's display name by explicitly setting `CFBundleDisplayName` in the `plist` file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8115312/188926

Answer (score 2):

Now it must be include following architecture.

armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64

Try this.