# Invalid Binary with Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, iphone-developer-program

I am in the process of submitting my first Ionic application to the store. However I am receiving an error every single time that I try to submit my binary to the store:

**Invalid Signature** - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The binary at path [Who Paid Last?.app/Who Paid Last?] contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate....

I have verified that my certificates are correct. I have even tried moving my .git folder outside of the directory, but still no luck. I have tried about 7 different configurations and still the same result time and time again.

The crazy thing is that after my archive has been built, I validate using XCode's validator. The validator says that my .ipa has zero errors and that it is ready for submission, but iTunes Connect says differently.

I have also tried following this [tutorial on troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853083/invalid-signature-invalid-binary-on-itunes-connect) but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had to do with the name of my app. The name of my application is Who Paid Last?, and come to find out, the "?" in the name is what was causing the issue. As soon as I removed it, the app was submitted just fine with out any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my error message was "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The binary at path [myApp.app/www/js/02_jshint.js] contains an invalid signature...."

Deleting the #!/usr/bin/env directive from the top of my 02_jshint.js file, then building the iOS version of your project from the CLI worked for me.