# Invalid Signature when update an app on Appstore after changing project to workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I've just added a frameworks to my old project by Cocoapods. Now I cannot submit the app to the AppStore, this is the error I was given:

> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>    and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>    process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>    deliver the corrected binary.

I've tried to follow these steps:

1. Edit my app's provision profile on Provision Potal and press Generate button.
2. Update my provision profiles in XCode by deleting contents of the folder `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` and then use Xcode 6's "fix code signing issues" to automatically download and reassign the profiles.
3. Then I deleted the "build" directory at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`
4. "Clean all" by pressing `Cmd + Option + Shift + K`

This is my Target's settings:
[image: Target's code signing settings]

Also, I've tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853083/invalid-signature-invalid-binary-on-itunes-connect).
No luck so far. So I'm wondering if changing from xcodeproj to xcworkspace or using Cocoapods have anything to do with the "Code signing" thing?

Comment: Have you check the provisioning profile? It should be distributed cerficate.

Comment: Its good but you should select proper provisioning profile rather than Automatic. it can also select another one. So better is select desired one.

Answer (score 1):

you probably deleted your profiles. Login with AppleID in xCode -> Prefferences -> then refresh your provision profiles. After that you will be able to see your profiles (if any created in Apple Membership Center) in the last picture posted.

First change "Provisioning Profile" then "Code Signing Identity".

For every app you should have a profile created in Apple Membership Center. And every app profile to be created you need a valid "Develeoper profile".
At the end you should have two Profiles: one profile as "x App Development" and one as "x App AppStore"

in practical terms: when you change "Provisioning Profile" then "Code Signing Identity" THEN set "developer" profile for DEBUGGING AND set "appstore" profile for RELEASING (packing the app to a final executable)

hope that helps