# Invalid Signature - Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I always get an email from apple about an Invalid Signature when I try to upload my archive. I tried using automatic signing first, changed it to manual then. Deleted all old certificates, cleaned the project, recreated certificates + profiles from developer portal. Still no success.

I did the code signing settings on the target level as well as the project level. I also have no special character in the Product Name.

I also checked the output of the codesign/security commands like it's described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853768/1468626)

Does anyone have an idea what else to try? I also contacted the apple support yesterday and I am waiting for an answer.

The email content:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Bier brauen Bier Rezepte". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [Bier brauen Bier Rezepte.app/Bier brauen Bier Rezepte] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Comment: I sent my project files to a friend today who signed other apps with his profile successfully and it fails for him as well. So it can't be a problem with the certificates.

Comment: Same problem here. i change the certificate, etc. nothing changed. You find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I just created a new ionic project via cli and copied my src folder into it. So some configuration was messed up. Can't tell which one.

Answer (score 4):

I will add my 2 cents here, I had the same problem a few days ago, and the reason was that I had in my assets a file with an `accentuated character` "é" in one of my assets files causing the binary check to fail.

Once removed the invalid signature error was gone, and the binary was validated by apple.

More info: [Avoid special characters in Executable names](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1510/_index.html)

Comment: Your two cents are worth a million! One of my resource files had a diacritic character...  You just saved my life... ;)

Comment: In my case, 3 files with 'space' causing this error, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify your app and display names again (it should be same) and make "Signing" again.
I found this info in this [blogpost](http://akhromieiev.com/tutorials/itunes-connect-invalid-signature-ionic-app-build/).

Comment: That wasn't the problem in my case.