# Xcode 7 submission error CEFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist may not contain any of these characters \ [ ] { } ( ) . + *

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've seen other posts with this issue but they are all old and not updated for Xcode 7.

I'm submitting an app with a + in the app name (for example appName+) and getting this error when achieving, submitting then uploading to the app store.

"This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CEFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist file, may not contain any of these characters \ [ ] { } ( ) . + *" Error ITMS-90121

Here is what I've tried to do to fix it and still getting the same error - Changed the entire project name and removed the +:
1) Changed Bundle display name from ${PRODUCT_NAME} to appName+. Didn't work.
2) Changed just the target name. Didn't work.
3) Changed just the target - build settings - packaging - product name. Didn't work.
4) Tried exporting the archive and uploading through Application Loader. Didn't work.

I can't figure out how to have my app name have a + in it but nothing in the plist using the + character. Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Open your info.plist and check whether there is such a key and what's the value of that

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what you're asking. I can't figure out how to have my app name have a + in it but nothing in the plist using the + character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115205/naming-an-ios-app-for-submission

Comment: @EugeneGordin changing the display name no longer works in Xcode 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm sure there are other ways to do this but this is what I did to fix it.

The error says the executable name can't have a + character. So I renamed the entire project by clicking the project on the left and on the top right of the utilities panel I typed a new name without +.

Then I went to the plist, found bundle name, and put the + in there. Submitted and worked like a charm.