# In Xcode 11.1 onward, Is there any way to have different Display Name and PRODUCT_NAME?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode11.1

Our app name contains a "+". Prior to Xcode 11.1 we could have a different Display name and `PRODUCT_NAME`. However, when we updated to Xcode 11.1, changing the app name automatically changes `PRODUCT_NAME`. When we upload this archive to the App Store, we get an error:

> 'invalid bundle' error because of the special character "+" in the
>   `PRODUCT_NAME`

"Display name" refers to the name we enter in the Display name field in our targets Info.plist.

Can we have a different Display name and Product name in Xcode 11.1 and later? Also, is there a way to successfully upload to the App Store while having a special character in `PRODUCT_NAME`?

Comment: Use bundle display name in your Info.plist

Comment: @DanielStorm, Thank you reaching out. But the problem is when we change Display name, Product Name automatically changes. This is one of the updates in XCode 11.1. Due to this feature, product name also contains "+" sign and hence fails to connect to app store.

Comment: @RVG try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34116008/466826

Comment: @ajreal This is working in XCode 7. In fact in all version below XCode 11. The problem arises in XCode 11 and later.

Comment: @RVG I've clarified what I was suggesting in an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219896/2108547

Comment: “ is there a way to successfully upload to the App Store while having a special character in PRODUCT_NAME?” Why? The product name is never seen by the user or the App Store. It can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode11, the app display name just set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`.
[image]
 that's display name always same as product name, try to update `CFBundleDisplayName`in the Info.plist.

Answer (score 5):

Update your `Product Name` in your targets Build Settings to not include the special character:

[image]

Navigate to your Info.plist for your target and add a new property `Bundle display name`:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>+Quotes</string>
```

[image]

Keep the `Bundle Name` property value as `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`.

The name that will be displayed below your app icon on device will be the value you've assigned to `Bundle Display Name`.

[image]