# How to make bundle display name more than 12 characters long

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In this screenshot, how did they make the app name more than 12 characters long? I know how to add a space between the words. The question is "Why app name "МойКиевстар..". truncated and "Монети Украины" not? " 
"Монети Украины" - 14 characters long!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Xcode 11.1 onward, Is there any way to have different Display Name and PRODUCT\_NAME?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219896/2108547)

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The font is not monospaced. You could achieve more than 12 characters using all “I”’s. Also note that the point at which the display name truncates will vary across devices.

Comment: How to set a display name different than the product name https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219896/2108547