# in Xcode, Bundle name in info.plist doesn't change bundle name (.app file name)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I'm developing iPhone app.

I changed `Bundle name` in info.plist.
But `.app` doen't change from `<project name>.app`.

*`.app` file is shown in the Products folder on the bottom of the Project Navigator(left side of the screen).

I believe `.app` file is called `bundle` and `Bundle name` should change `.app`'s name.
Am I wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5791165/119114)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the applications name(also the display name) is set by a variable called product name .U can change this is in the build settings for target

Comment: thanks. `product name` changed `.app` name. What is `Bundle name` in info.plist? Or why `Bundle name` doesn't work?

Comment: bundle display name changes only the display name..ie how it appears under the icon in the iphone...usually a variable ${PRODUCT NAME} is set as the default..ie whatever you enter as the product name it appears here also... if u think the answer is satisfactory pls vote up :)

Comment: thanks. but i know how `bundle display name` works. what i wanna know is how `bundle name` works. do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

I dunno if i am getting your question right !

but if you just want to change the name of the project you can
just click on the project name in the project navigator twice with one second gap between the two clicks !!

if you want to change the name of the application the one will appear  in the iPhone device

you may write it on the infoPlist.strings as this

> "CFBundleDisplayName" = "youAPPName";

i hope that helps

Comment: @MOthman thanks. but i know both of them. I really wanna change `.app` name. But sujith answered that. And I'll ask about role of CFBundleName(not CFBundleDisplayName) in another question.