# iOS Bundle Identifier error

Tags: ios, deployment

In my build settings, under the Code Signing Identity section I keep getting this error:

COMPANY_NAME APP_NAME Enterprise (for bundle identifiers 'com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME') profile doesn't match bundle identifier 'com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME.APP_NAME'

I am trying to resolve a ipa not installing problem and am wondering if this could be the cause?

Edit: I should add the proper case for this: it should read com.company_name.app_name doesn't match com.company_name.app_name.APP_NAME

where APP_NAME is the name of my app (EBUS) in the Project Name section of the Identity panel. In the summary, this appears, com.company_name.app_name.APP_NAME and the trailing APP_NAME is greyed out and cannot be edited.

If so, how do I resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: Solution is there in the question itself. Your bundleId and the profileID are different. Check that

Comment: @Mid - I know they are different but how do I resolve it? See my edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twice 'com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME.**APP_NAME**', maybe?

Just put your bundle ID like this: 'com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME' so it can match your provisioning profile 'com.COMPANY_NAME.APP_NAME'...

Comment: Why can't you edit it? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929715/cant-change-bundle-id-in-project-greyed-out // Edit the .plist directly.

Comment: For other wayward souls who also find themselves in one of Dante's Seven Circles of Apple app deployment my problem was the product variable names was being dynamically attached to the bundle identifier in my info.plist. It'll look something like this.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}. Since it is dynamic you cannot edit in the summary (hence the greyed out). I am not sure how it got attached but the resolution is to edit the plist directly and remove the dynamic reference. to the last I grapple with thee;from hell’s heart I stab at thee;for hate’s sake I spit my last breath at thee.

Comment: Oh, and run over to the linked SO thread in Jacky Boy's comment and give Aleross an up vote for his answer.

Comment: The dynamic reference @PruitIgoe is there by default. Just create a new project and see for yourself.

Comment: I did before coming here - part of my frustration. Why is that done by default?

Comment: It's a good habit to have things dynamic. It avoids many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle Id should be usually kept in a simple format.. 
Like: com.anyName.AppName.

If you are unable to edit, you can also check in your App's ".plist" file and edit it from there.

EDIT: you should also go the Apple developer portal and check the App Id you have given to your App. Best measures are that this App id to match the bundle Id.