# Renaming project in xCode 4 causes SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

I've renamed a project in xCode 4 by slowly double clicking the project name and then following the directions.  I then Build and Run with no errors, but when I select a popover in the app simulator get a SIGABRT.  This works fine in the original project.  Other parts of the renamed app work OK.  I've done a Clean and that doesn't help.

Are there other changes I need to make manually to rename a project?

Comment: Have you tried to reset the simulator as well?

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel  Yes, I've tried that and it didn't fix it.  The error message includes "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app suggests you also change the product name in the target. This should usually work.

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel The target product name was already changed.  I think I've just got to dig into the code and figure out why I'm getting the NSException which is causing the SIGABRT with the new name.

Comment: Sorry that I could not help you. I hope you can find the error.

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel Vielen Dank...Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by some forgotten value in the Build settings like old name for info file, app delegate etc ...