# iOS: Running different apps on device

Tags: ios, certificate

I'm a novice iOS developer and got my iOS developer program account, I setup the iOS certificate and Provisioning Profile and I can run my test app on my device(iPad). My question is if I want to run different test apps(imagine couple Apple sample codes) on my device without replacing the last tested app on my device(I mean keep all of them on my device at the end of test) what would be the trick here? I know each app has it's own bundle identifier, but how to manage this scenario for running all of them on the device with the same iOS Certificate/Provisioning Profile?

Comment: So you want different versions of the same app on your iOS device?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly I want, also curious to know how can run couple different apps on device too

Comment: You can. I have 4 different apps on my device right now, all written by me.

Comment: Also increment the version number in the build settings when you want a major revision.

Comment: When I change my product name and try to run it on device, debugger console says: The program being debugged is not being run... it seems it can not run it with different name unless you delete the app on device(means not able to keep two versions of that). I see after the change of product name, it still refer to the previous app(the earlier app which I changed the product name). Do you think something else is involve with this, something like bundle identifier that is same for both versions? I also changed the Project Name, it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the Name of the project and it should refactor. Change the name on the root of files & folders in xcode. You can click on it and it'll let you change the name. In Build Settings Properties change the name under there as well. Click at the very top of your list of files where it says the name of your project and it'll bring up the build properties.

Comment: Sorry did't get your point.Can you explain it little more, the projects have different name... and I have to change the bundle identifier to make it same for all if I want to run them on device, that ends up with replacing each other..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, there are two parts of your questions:

1. Yes, you can run many (distinct) apps on your device.
2. To have multiple version of the same app running on your device, all you need is change app's product name to a different name, app1, app2, etc.  It is a relatively easy process to do it.  This SO Q/A[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app) has the instructions.  You do not need to rename your project or any thing else.  Just make a copy of the project and follow the instructions to make a new product name.

Comment: When I change my product name and try to run it on device, debugger console says: The program being debugged is not being run... it seems it can not run it with different name unless you delete the app on device(means not able to keep two versions of that). I see after the change of product name, it still refer to the previous app(the earlier app which I changed the product name). Do you think something else is involve with this, something like bundle identifier that is same for both versions?