# What is the right way to "save as" an iPad project?

Tags: ios, sdk

I would like to build a new project based upon my existing.  Since there are internal names that need to be changed to correspond with the project file names, I don't know the simple way to accomplish this without a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps I have done:

1. Copy the whole folder of that project and rename the folder to whatever new name you want.
2. Following the direction in the answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app) to change the "product name".

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do NOT "save as" any project. Because to handle two copies of a same code is very very painful.

If you just want give your project a new name or make some new build settings, add a new "target" is good enough.

And if you want to use your existing project in another project, simply add it as a sub-project is a better way.

But just try to avoid to have many copies of one code, it's hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: I agree with your concern, but this is not the case for maintaining two copies.  I like your recommendation for creating the new target and the subproject.  However, this time, I just wanted to try some new concepts but not disrupt the original.  Later I may merge - but more likely just throw away.  It is essentially a poor man's branch without the fancy source control :)