# importing one Xcode project into another

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to import one of my xcode projects into another, and I was just wondering if there were some best practices for this task, or if anyone has any advice how to make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by import.

If you want to do a framework then you'll want this.

[Framework Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html)

If you want to do a shared library then you'll want this.

[Shared Libs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: hmmm, maybe this is beyond my techniqueal knowledge, but what I would really just like to do is move all of my classes and xibs into a different project. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, ya you can just open them in the finder from the 'old project' and drag and drop them into Xcode on the 'new project'. Just make sure that you select the copy checkbox.

Comment: But if you want to create a new project from all classes and sibs ... Try the answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447337/what-is-the-right-way-to-save-as-an-ipad-project/7448010#7448010

Answer (score 0):

Just click on .xcodeproj file and it will be automatically opened in whatever version of xcode installed in your system and if the project was created in an older version just click on "Modernise Project" which you can find at the bottom of your xcode and xcode will take care of the rest.