# Do users see the bundle ID used in iOS apps?

Tags: ios

Will the bundle ID that I'm using in my project (and which will be used when I submit my app to AppStore) be seen by users anywhere?

The URL I use in the bundle ID in my project is different than my company URL.  I own the URL that is used by my bundle ID; I just don't want to disclose that one to users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the bundle identifier is fo your reference..  It will not be displayed in the app store..  Only the App ID will be displayed in the URL.  And that will not change for a app.

You can even have a different App name and Bundle Identifier..

Comment: Thanks ... may i ask you also from the app name that appear AppStore/iTune is displayed. I mean where I spasify the app name.

Comment: I have posted the answer here.. Please see this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app/7371446#7371446

Comment: could I also change bundle ID in my project settings?

Comment: I think if you do that you have to create a new App Id in your apple account and you have to reassign the provisioning in apple developer account..If you to that you will  be ok.