# App name won't display on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My app won't display the app name under the icon on the home screen when testing in the simulator or on my iPhone.

My app name is listed in the Bundle Display Name and Bundle Name in the plist. The product name is also listed in build settings. Additionally, I've tried deleting the app, cleaning, and rebuilding but that has not worked.

Has anyone else had this happen or have any ideas as to what I may be missing? Thanks!

Comment: what is the app name? if it's something like "Supercalifragileisticexpialidocious" that might be problematic.

Comment: Its seven letters long so I don't think thats the issues.

Answer (score 0):

sanity check:

- delete the app
- reboot device
- restart Xcode
- select `Info.plist` in Project Navigator
- confirm that `CFBundleDisplayName` is *AppName*
- build/run

if that's not working, there could be some cruft in the make files, even with more details it would be difficult to remotely diagnose

a laborious workaround: start project from scratch and add in all the file to the new project

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I found the solution by going over info.plist more carefully. A while ago, I followed one of the instructions on this thread when I wanted to change my app name (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app). One answer (of two) that I tried was to change the Bundle Display Name in the info.plist. I think this was the problem because I just switched the bundle display name back to ${PRODUCT_NAME} and it worked.