# Renaming iOS project in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I need to rename an iOS project. Is there a way to do this without starting a whole new project?

All other info I found were related to Xcode 4 or old and those methods seem to crash the project - I created a snapshot before I tried any name changing.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/1373105. Is fully responded there step by step related to Xcode 5.

Comment: I'm using this to rename my iOS project: http://github.com/ytbryan/rename

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For changing schema name

First go to "Manage Schemes…"

[image: manage schema]

then edit scheme name

[image: edit scheme]

Finally, it's changed

[image: updated name]

Answer (score 21):

Select the project name in Xcode :

[image]

It will take sometime to analyse again another window will be shown as:
[image]

After this you need to change the manage scheme as :

[image]

[image]

Comment: also you have to set Toolbar project-name with manage schemes .

Comment: @DhavalBhadania: Thanks, i updated my answer with schemes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed screenshots. Very useful.