# Renaming App Failed after following Technical Q&A QA1625

Tags: ios, xcode, cl

After changing my app's name per Technical Q&A QA1625, I get this error message:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: file not found: /Users/.../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/**oldName.app**/**oldName**

This directory has the correct names, i.e.  **newName.app**/**newName**...  Why is Xcode looking for **oldName**?  I'm extremely reluctant to hack this by renaming these files manually.  I have looked through the other StackOverflow questions and nothing there seems to work.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Try going to Xcode -> Window -> Organizer and deleting the derived data for your app.

Comment: It might me obvious, but have you cleaned your project before trying to build it?

Comment: I tried both.  Didn't work.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Here is a hack that worked.  I Went to:  Basic + Combined/Build Settings/Testing/Test host/Debug/ and changed oldName to newName.  I sure would like to know if there is some other deeper problem that will nail me a some future time.  thanks again folks

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. I solve it by following [Renaming iOS project in xCode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419822/renaming-ios-project-in-xcode-5)

which says you need also rename the schema name.

Hope this helps :) BTW, I am using Xcode 6.3.2.