# Trouble changing app's name in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, plist, xcode5.1

I am currently using xcode 5.1

I have successfully changed an app's name before using the same steps described [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/3344977).

But for some reason I am having trouble right now. Usually, I have experienced [this same screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjesb.png). but this time when I changed the name it did not fully change everything.

When I view my project's targets, the old app name is still being used. If I clean and build my project, it will show the old name very quickly in the "progress bar" up at the top of xcode.

If I look at my project's supporting files folder, the plist still has the old app name ie. `old-app-name-Info.plist`

So far I have manually changed the project name, changed the bundle identifier, changed the Product Name in the Build Settings, and changed the name of the Scheme. I don't know what else to do.

The app now has the correct name when I run it on the simulator or on my iPhone, but the old app name is still being used throughout various areas in project folder's, xcode settings, etc.

I just want to fully change everything that use's the old app's name and make them use the new app name.

EDIT: Here's another example. If I go to the File Inspector tab the correct name is shown for the project, but if I go to the Issue Navigator tab it shows the old app name at the very top.

What do I need to do to change everything over?

Comment: Why do you need to change the name everywhere?

Comment: Because it makes no sense to have files named after the old app name, when the app has a new name.

Comment: I faced similar problem once. But I just changed the name then I didn't had any problem with older names. Though I searched but it didn't worked. :(

Comment: Did you actually quit Xcode and throw away the DerivedData folder?

Comment: @matt I did quit and restart xcode. However I never "threw away" the DerivedData folder.

Comment: Try it please. I can't reproduce your problem with the Issue Navigator so I have to assume that something has gotten stuck somewhere. We want to remove all cache files and force a complete reindex of the project.

Comment: @matt Are you sure it's ok to delete the DerivedData folder in Finder? It contains a lot of folders.

Comment: @matt I ended up figuring it out. Also, thanks for teaching me about the DerivedData folder. I just read about it some more and now I understand why it's ok to delete the contents: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/3344977

Comment: And see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Comment: Thanks for linking me. That's a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up finally changing it for me.

I went to the Project Navigator tab in xcode and clicked on my project. I then double clicked the target that still had the old app name, changed the name to the new app name, and hit the return key.

Everything is now correct and changed to the new app name. However, I still have no idea why the SO Answer that I linked to in my question did not get the job done in the first place.

I have used that solution several times over the past 6 months and it has always worked perfectly for me so I have no idea why it did not work this time.

Comment: Great that you figured it out. Yes, when you change the project name correctly (select project name at top of Project Navigator, hit Return, type new name, hit Return) Xcode should change everything to match (except scheme names). I don't know why it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `plist` file and edit **bundle name** and **bundle display** name as you want.

[image: Tricj]

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to change the application name on devices go to the info.plist file on your application and Change Bundle Name to (yourAppName)

That's work for me. (XCode 6.3.2)