# Rename XCode project AND iOS app, but retain old app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to further develop a sample application while keeping the original on my phone at the same time.

All answers here [how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) do not work completely because the new app will overwrite the original one, therefore anytime I want the original one back on my phone I have to run ('install') that one again. There must be some additional step that has to be taken.

I apologize for creating a new question, but I cannot comment on the old one due to a lack of reputation and I see no point in answering a bunch of random questions that other people are more qualified to do just to gain some.

Answer (score 1):

1. I recommend you to create a new target in existing project. You can do this by duplicating exiting target.
2. In this target change bundle identifier. (New target's general tab) So it will not overwrite existing application.
3. change Bundle display name to identify your new application from exiting one. (New target's info tab)

This way you can have files only related to you sample application. When you want to build original target you just have to change the target from XCode and build.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had already changed the target and the bundle display name, but not the bundle identifier, at least not at the same time. This will do for now, however it's not recommended according to [this comment on one answer in the question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app#comment34898916_16190307)

Comment: The link question is on renaming the iOS App name. Your case is different. Since you want to keep 2 installations of the same application. iOS is keeping track of the application using bundle identifiers. So it's essential to have different ids if you want to keep multiple copies in same application.

Comment: No, I never said I wanted 2 installations of the same application, although I understand this is probably semantics. What I want to do is use an existing app as a starting point for a new app, while retaining the original - and without having to copy/paste the whole code and the settings.

Comment: oh ok. Even though I misunderstood requirement, happy that I could help you in some way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on your project's name here so that it is selectable and editable.

[image]

I doubt it will overwrite your old app because it has a different name. I haven't tested this on any iOS device but in the simulator it doesn't delete the old version.