# Rename project in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

This error appears after I renamed the project in Xcode:

> error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and 'Build failed'.
>
> ld: file not found:ld: file not found: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RenameProjectRenamed-glxemlqfmpgiasemfzifmxysyxpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RenameProject.app/RenameProject

Do you have some ideas of that?

Comment: You're going to need to post more details that that. There are many reasons that a linker can fail. It displays a verbose log; can you copy the result here?

Comment: ld: file not found: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RenameProjectRenamed-glxemlqfmpgiasemfzifmxysyxpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RenameProject.app/RenameProject
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 29):

Try building a new scheme of your app. It worked for me!

[image]

Comment: The other methods failed for me, this was the one that finally worked for me after I had tried the Ravi Garg's method

Comment: @user35443 I couldn't post images at the time due to my low reputation, sorry! All good now though

Comment: I spent 2 days going through a million methods and this was the only thing that finally worked for me. Eternally grateful to you @MaxFriedman

Comment: If you are in mad rush to submit app to appstore and due to some silly name related thing it got rejected , this is the solution you should go with.

Answer (score 14):

Xcode 6 (as of 6.1) forgets to rename the Test Host setting correctly.  Go in to the project settings -> Test target settings, and change Test Host setting to match to the new name.  See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Saved me a ton of time thanks. And as of 6.3.1 still a "feature"

Answer (score 1):

When you rename your project name, the previous derived data (with your previous project name) will remain in  Xcode, so you need to do the following steps:

1. On top bar of Xcode, *Window* → *Organizer* → *Projects*.
2. You can find the arrow mark (->) respect to the derived data of your project, open it.
3. Clear all the derived data contains in that folder.
4. Remove the previously installed app from the simulator and testing device (If you are running on device).
5. Clean and run your project again.

**Note**: If you still get this error please close the Xcode and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project with a new name, then copy (manually) all the files from the previous project. You can also try renaming the files back,

Answer (score -1):

I also solved it by selecting your projectTest file from TARGET.

In the Host Application, select your project from dropdown only if it show custom.