# Changing app name for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an app called ABC and now I want to change the name of the app. But I cannot figure out where to change it. I searched SO but couldn't find an answer which enabled me to change the name.
The Product Name is set to the correct name (which is not ABC) in the section Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name. 
Whatever I do, the name remains ABC as you can see from this screenshot from Application Loader[image]

Any ideas what to do ?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app and so is the answer provided by wtznc below.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly 2 steps for renaming an app name in Xcode (If you want to change the project name too) -

1. Double click of project and rename it, it will automatically show you option where all it is going to rename.
   [image]
2. Go to scheme settings - manage scheme and change name there.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution proposed but it didn't solve my problem. It turned out, I had to create a new provisioning profile with the correct name.