# App Rejected because of same name in iTunes?

Tags: ios, xcode

In iTunes store an App has same name like my App. So I want to change my app name. I have changed my App name in XCode. Should I have to change all the folder too ?
Should I have to change bundle ID also ?

Comment: ya no need to change the all folder , just change the target name and also change the name in iTunes connect also bro

Comment: folders name yum mathunuma Xcode la? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ila bro thevai ila , check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app

Comment: The bundle id does not even have to bear the app's name, as long as You have Your own company name there and nobody has the same name it's fine.
As for the folder names it's also up to You, the name of the app is the name of App package in filesystem, as there cannot be two files with the same name You have to have unique name for Your app (in case user download both apps with the same name), the folders inside the package can be named whatever You like as they already are in their own packages.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to change it at two places :

1. The name of you product app
2. The name of your app in iTunes

That's all