# Bundle ID confusion

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, identifier

When I created my app, the bundle identifier I set changed the space of the title of the app with a hyphen(-) and now that my app is on the AppStore it has the bundle ID with that hyphen. Now the thing is that I am setting some in app purchases for the new version of the app and when I create a bundle ID for an in app purchase with the same bundle ID as the app ( `APP_IDENTIFIER.IAP_IDENTIFIER`), I get an error saying that the ID cannot have hyphens. I believe that deleting the hyphen on the iAP ID it will acknowledge the app but before starting all the work I want to be sure, so what do you think? There is no problem if the in app purchase ID isn't exactly the same as the app ID?

Comment: You can have the name of the app be different from the bundle ID. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/239006/451475) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode -> Select Project -> Go To Target -> Info tab -> Add a key named **'Bundle Display Name (CFBundleDisplayName)'** if it is not already there.

Enter your desired name here.

Build & Run.

**EDIT:**

As for your question about IAP ID, you are correct - there is no restriction on how you set your IAP ID - except that it should be unique across app store. You can ensure uniqueness by basing it off your app ID.