# App in xcode project isnt changing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I deleted my old Xcode project (and delete it from the trash) and started a new one with the same name as the old one but when I open the app in the simulator, it is the exact same app as from the old deleted Xcode project. I deleted the app from the simulator and ran the one from the new Xcode project but it is still the same app as from the old Xcode project. 
There are no errors and I even reset the simulator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps that you can follow when you face such scenarios::

- Clean your project
- Delete the derived data
- reset the simulator
- restart the system. :P :P

I know it may sound weird, but Xcode can be weird sometimes.

Comment: How do you restart the system, your computer?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, press Command+K to clean your project folder. Then run the simulator again.

Comment: I am still having the same issue