# iOS PHPhotoLibrary performChanges title localization

Tags: ios, localization, phasset

In my project(need localization), I need to perform a image delete request like this:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:self.phassets];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```

But the alert tile `images` is not localized:
[image]

I have tried to add `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName` to the localization file, but it does not work.

How Can I manage to localization some "inner title" of iOS?

Comment: I think system alerts will only display in the phone language.

Comment: @ShahiM , No , `images` is the name of my app, I think there is a bundle name or something like that I can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After All of my research, I have not find a way of change this, maybe apple does not support this, as is the localization of  `identity` or `target name` of the app. I use a compromise way of changing it to another string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app).