# Adjusting the name of an unreleased iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am about to finish up with version 1.0 of my app and I have a quick question regarding naming and changing the name. The app is called Up My Street and that is also what the Xcode project is called. However, I want the app to appear in the App Store as Jolly Rancher: Up My Street, but for the App to appear on the device below the icon as Up My Street.

What's required to make this happen, either the naming of the Xcode project and the naming of the App in iTunes Connect.

To be clear, I'm not asking how to change the name of the application. I understand how to do that. I don't understand where the name needs to be what, between Xcode and iTunes Connect.

So if the App Store name is what I put in iTunes Connect; I guess in iTunes Connect I put it as Jolly Rancher: Up My Street but I keep the Xcode project still as Up My Street?

Comment: App store shows app name on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the name of an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app)

Comment: Thats @Desdenova - that makes sense. And Luk.. I'm aware on how to change the name; my question was where does the name have to be Jolly Rancher: Up My Street and where does it need to be called Up My Street.

Comment: But I still don't quite get where I should name this. So do I name it Up My Street on Xcode and Jolly Rancher: Up My Street in iTunes Connect? But then won't that make the name of the app below the icon to Jolly Rancher: Up My Street?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the app that you set in iTunes Connect will be used on the App Store (for display and search purposes).

The name that you set in your project will be used on the device (below the icon name on SpringBoard and other locations).

Note that Apple allow you to have slightly different names and icons in both locations (mostly due to space constraints on the device), but they must not be confusing.

Also note that I don't know what's your relationship with The Hershey Company, but of course Jolly Rancher is a trademark, and unless allowed under fair use or similar provisions, you may not be able to use that name without their authorisation.

Comment: Dear @Jcaron - many thanks for your help with that and that clears it up perfectly. I really appreciate it! Oh.. And Sorry, Jolly Rancher was just a name I saw on my desk of a sweet - it's not the real company name (sorry, should have mentioned that in the question!).