# how can i change the name of my mobile app using xcode7

Tags: xcode, swift, project

My app is currently called a silly name. Does anyone know how to change it using xcode7?. By app name i mean when you see the little app icon on the home screen with the apps name below it.

i have looked at other answers but they are only explained using Xcode 4-6.

xcode7 only!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the name of an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to simply change your app's name in Springboard (aka Home screen), without renaming your project, targets and etc (which is always a lot of pain), you can just change "display name" in your app's Info.plist.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html

As far as I know, it applies to all versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This did not change at all for quite a long time, so any older Xcode version answer does still apply:

> In Project Navigator select your project > select your build target >
>   go to Build settings > Product name

Answer (score 0):

Just change product name for your target.

[image]