# Given name does not display as the app name and , Project name display as app name when installed the app, in iOS, Apple, AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, universal, submission

- I submitted my app to the apple app store and it is In Review.
- And at the same time I requested for the TestFlight (beta app review).
- It was successfull and now I can send invitations to the external users properly.
- Now , my problem is , it shows the given name as the app name, when I submit to the app store correctly (In TestFlight). but after I download it, it show the the project name of my app.

**Note : As an example, I create the xcode project and a I give the name as "MyAppOne". after that when I submit it to the app store, I give the app name as "MyAppTwo". so when it shows to user for download,app name displays as "MyAppTwo" (the given name while submission to the app store) and after users downloaded it, the app name shows as "MyAppOne" (which the name given when I create the xcode project)**

- Does anyone has an idea of this.
- Do I have to resubmit the app to app store.

Hope your help with this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Badly we cannot change the app name (

> **display name when user installed the app to iphone/ipad , not the name display in app store.**

) if the app has approved already.

- If we want to change it, we have to do it with the next version of the app, that means we have to submit the app again as another version.
- so before we submit the next version of the app (which have already appreoved), we have to change the `Bundle Display Name` in `info.plist` like below.

[image]

- can do it with changing the `Bundle Name`, but better to change `Bundle Display Name`

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Targets in Xcode
- "Get Info" on your project's target
- Search for "Product Name" under "Packaging". Change the value of what
  you want the new program name to be.

you can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) fore more details with screenshots and different ways!