# How to change app display name in Xcode 8 to add a space

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to put a space in my app name (standalone sticker pack) in Xcode 8. The solutions I've seen on here are to change the Product Name (in packaging) or to change the "Bundle Display Name".

I've changed the product name and that hasn't worked (I cleaned, rebuilt, reset content and settings in simulator and logged out of xcode, logged back in and rebuilt app).

I can't see "Bundle Display Name" anywhere. Should I add it and if so, how do I do that?

I've read the thread [How to change the name of an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) and done the suggestions, but it's still showing in simulator and testflight without the space. Have I missed something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16190307/1226963

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the name of an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app)

Comment: Thanks Maddy - I've tried those ideas in that thread but no luck. I'll play around again.

Comment: Ok, I've change product name and bundle display name but it's still showing in the simulator without the space. I've cleared the simulator as well. It's also showing up as without the space in testflight. I'm not sure what else to do? Everyone else has spaces in their app names so I feel like it shouldn't be this hard. Should I just assume it will be correct if I submit to Apple or have I missed something?

Comment: @rach did you figure it out? I am facing the same issue..

Answer (score 61):

**Steps:**

**1.** Open project `Info`.

**2.** Add a property `Bundle display name` into `Custom iOS Target Properties`. (as "Key")

**3**. Enter the display name, that will be shown on iPhone/iPad screen under an app icon. (as "Value")

It's my solution that works properly. Also you should delete previously installed app and reinstall it.
[image: Solution]

Comment: Not everyone can see the images you include. You should consider writing out the steps so that the answer is complete and does not rely on eyesight.

Comment: Use 'Bundle display name' rather than 'Bundle Display Name'

Answer (score 20):

Just go to `Target -> General -> In Identity -> Display Name`. By default, it has your app display name which is unhighlighted. Enter here your new app display name.

[image]

Comment: iOS App display name contains 10-14 characters (including spaces) and it depends on the width of your letters. Once a limit reached its automatically remove spaces from the app name and shows name with the truncate tail format.

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to change app display name.

**Solution 1:**

Goto `Targets` -> `General` Tab -> `Identity` section

In this you’ll find `Display Name` field where you set app display name.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Solution 2:**

`Bundle Display Name` property is not present by default in Info.plist. You need to explicitly add this property.

Below image shows how to add this property.

[image: Screenshot 2]

*Note: If still this new name is not reflected in your app then delete app and install it again.*

Answer (score 5):

When creating a new project, Xcode uses the *Product Name* by default. You can just change that in your Build Settings, even setting separate names for your schemes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After changed Bundle display name make a Clean of project.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the **Bundle Display Name (CFBundleDisplayName)** in your Info.plist file
2. Check if you have any localization (InfoPlist.strings) files, and change the corresponding **CFBundleDisplayName** values in those files to the localized values.
3. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Info.plist and add "Bundle display name" and set your rename in value box make sure the Bundle display name type is a string run the project automatically it will be changed

Answer (score -1):

For xcode 9.3, Goto Targets, Build Settings, under packaging change Produce Name.  See below screen shot

[image]

After this if it not changed, clean product to reopen X code.

Comment: Wrong answer. Product Name cannot contain space, because this is app identifier.

Comment: @dandepeched Thank you. I edited my image see now, is it ok

Comment: the image is fine, but this does not answer the topic, because author asks about adding space in name