# How to add space in app name iOS 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I have tried many ways to add space for my app name but still couldn't figure it out the right way on iOS 11. I also tried all methods on stackoverflow but still can't do it.  My app name on iOS device now is something like this "MyAppNa..." Any suggestions?

This is my part of my info.list code.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My App Name</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add spaces to the app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275567/how-can-i-add-spaces-to-the-app-name)

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759334/how-to-change-app-display-name-in-xcode-8-to-add-a-space

Comment: I tried all of them but none works on iOS 11.

Answer (score 20):

Add this key in info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App&#x2007;Name</string>
```

Remember **`&#x2007;`** not worked in build setting of the project.**`&#x2007;`** this will work as space

```
Output:
App Name
```