# iOS App Name Not Correct

Tags: ios, app-store

I’ve made an app and have put in on the App Store, but for some reason the app name in the App Store does not show up after installing, instead it shows up the name that I created it with in Xcode. Why doesn’t the name that I named it for the App Store show up?

Example:
The bundle identifier is

com.companyname.namegive

The namegiven is showing up when installing it and not the name that shows up in the App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle display name (the name that displays under the app icon) and the name in the App Store are **two different things**. You can only change the bundle display name in your IDE (e.g. Xcode) and you can only change the name displayed in the App Store in iTunes Connect.

[Read more about changing an iOS app's name here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238980/3151675)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!