# When adding a website to iOS homescreen it appears "App" in name field, how to change?

Tags: html, ios, meta-tags

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv3ac.jpg) When adding a website to iOS homescreen it appears "App" in name field, how to change?
The Same on Android phones, it always use "app" as icon name.

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: I've added an Image, when I try add my website to the home of my smartphone, it automatically set the name "App" how to change?

Comment: Please do a little research. This is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/238980/1531971 If not, tell us _why_ you feel it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @jdv it's not a duplicate. In my case it's not an app. It's a website. When I want to add this website to my iphone Home Screen, that preset name appears, got it?

Comment: @Elisino, Got it. Your question is probably off-topic then, as it doesn't seem to have to do with coding on iOS. Maybe check on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jdv it happens also on Android Phone. I think I should change something in HTML but I don't know what

Comment: Different platforms will determine this in different ways. There are even apps that help you do this. At the end of the day, your platform is going to create a "manifest" of some kind. How that is created or edited by a platform because of a gesture is not really on topic here. There are Q&A about programmatically creating site shortcuts, in which case you have control over the manifest to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want your website to have a default name when added to the home screen. These solutions should solve your problem.

For iOS:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Short name">
```

For Android:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="Short name">
```

You can read further about iOS compatibility [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)