# Change package name and app name in react native

Tags: react-native

Hi how can I change the package name and the name that will be displayed on the phone in react-native ? I've tried to change the name in app.json and package.json and then delete `android` and `ios` folders but when I want to regenerate these folders with `react-native upgrade` it doesn't work..

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you referring to the app's name that'll be displayed on the phone?

For iOS, you can edit the name directly in XCode. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app).

For Android, you can edit the app name in `strings.xml` file located at `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`.

`<string name="app_name">Your app's name</string>`

Answer (score 1):

**1) Install**

```
yarn global add react-native-rename
or
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

**2) Rename your project**

```
react-native-rename "New Project Name"
```

For more details [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

Answer (score 0):

To change app name and package name, run this command

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```