# After updating to latest swift version I got the error: No such module "NewAppName"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, migration

After changing my apps name according to [How to change the name of an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) **Cavier Cadiz answer** everything was great. 
When I tried to update to the latest swift version I got the error below in the tests supporting file.

```
import XCTest
@testable import NewAppName                           ! No such module "NewAppName"
```

The app before the name changing updates to latest swift version without any problems. Anybody knows what I might did wrong while renaming the app? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you removed / re-added the product of `NewAppName` back to the test target (Target Dependencies)? Sometimes that helps

Comment: if you are using podfile please update the pod and run the project again
if you are not using podfile please clean the build and delete derived data and run again


it worked for me.

Comment: I wrote OldAppName @testable import NewAppName

Comment: After many trials I wrote OldAppName  after the import, then I run facing the same problem. Then write the NewAppName again and run again. Unexpectedly there was no problem at all. I don't know why. Is there any recommended source (site, book) where Xcode is explained?