# Change splash screen text in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen, launch

I am using React Native iOS (not Expo) and recently changed my app name. The problem is, the old app name is still visible on the splash screen (aka launch screen). How can I change the text on the splash screen? I cannot find info on how to do this for iOS, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you update your app name *correctly*, the splash screen text will be automatically updated too. I updated my app name in Xcode using the steps below -- and this fixed the problem of updating my splash screen text:

1. I followed the instructions here to rename my app in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989/14755660
2. In the Xcode drop-down menu, went to "Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme..." and next to "executable" selected my new app name.
3. Voila... splash screen and app name updated!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a cache issue with your simulator, so you might need to clear emulator cache, Close simulator and run following command on terminal: `xcrun simctl erase all`
This command will clear the cache of emulator now run the project again.